# My first Stored Procedure is not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This works:

mysql> select user_id, meta_value from 1_um where meta_key='1_caps';

What I want is:

insert into 1_um (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) values (user_id=$uid, meta_key='2_caps', meta_value=$mval);

But I keep getting zero rows affected from my attempts at a SP.  Here's what I have:

Delimiter //

create procedure import_um()

BEGIN

```
declare done int default FALSE; 
declare $uid bigint(20) unsigned default 0; 
declare $mval longtext default ""; 
declare curs cursor for select user_id, meta_value from 1_um where meta_key='1_caps'; 
declare continue handler for not found set done = TRUE; 
open curs; 
read_loop:  LOOP 
    fetch curs into $uid,$mval; 
    insert into 1_um (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) values (user_id=$uid, meta_key='2_caps', meta_value=$mval); 
if done then leave read_loop; 
end if; end LOOP; close curs; END//
```

moving "if done then leave read_loop; end if;" directly below the fetch statement (above the insert statement) has no effect, either.

It appears that the fetch into variable,var2 is not working, as I try to replace the insert statement with select concat('my var is', $uid); and get nothing to STDOUT.

the table 1_um contains four columns:  umid (auto inc), user_id, meta_key, meta_value.  Do I have to select all of them into the cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a loop in your code?  Just use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into 1_um (user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
    select user_id, '2_caps', meta_value
    from 1_um
    where meta_key = '1_caps';
```

No doubt a bit part of your problem is the misformed `VALUES` clause (you have boolean expressions for the values, which doesn't seem right).  You should learn how to use `VALUES` correctly as well.  But for this problem, use the correct SQL construct.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!  I know I have much to learn... I wish people would stop downvoting my questions :/  I don't see how I failed to demonstrate research effort or how the question was not useful.